# Redirect to login if user not logged in - Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, authentication

I am getting a `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.logOut')` when trying to implement a logout with the following code. I also have tried just putting the contents of the `logOut` function inside of where I currently call the logOut function, but getting same `this` error.

```
export class ContactPage {

  user: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authData: AuthData) {

  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (!user) {
        console.log("user is not logged in");
        this.logOut();
      } else {
        console.log("user is logged in");
        return;
      }    
    });
  }

  logOut() {
    this.authData.logoutUser().then(() => {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(Login);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `this` is different in your callback (due to a different scope). To fix the scope, you can bind the function in the constructor.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authData: AuthData) {
    // This line says that every time onAuthCallback is called, the
    // value of 'this' in the function is the same as what it is here.
    this.onAuthCallback = this.onAuthCallback.bind(this);
}

onAuthCallback(user) {
    if (!user) {
        console.log("user is not logged in");
        this.logOut();
    } else {
        console.log("user is logged in");
        return;
    }    
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
    // When the callback is triggered, it will have the 
    // proper value for 'this'.
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthCallback);
}
```